# android OOM using picasso library

Tags: android, image, out-of-memory, picasso

WHAT IM DOING

I'm using the picasso library to display a bunch of images intended to be wallpapers in a gridview.

THE PROBLEM

Selecting an image shows it full screen in a new fragment, this works most of the time but sometimes throws an OOM exception.

In the new fragment with the full sized image I have used `.fit()` to make the image full screen which makes the app hang for some time but eventually shows the image, most of the time, but selecting one, pressing back, and selecting another stops it working it just shows my other `.load()` image,

WHAT IVE DONE

ive used .skipmemorycache() which is deprecated and ive allowed for large heap in my manifest, the images are in the app not URLs and they are pretty big, but is there a way to show the images full screen without the lag and to maybe clear it from memory onbackpressed? if i use .resize() the whole thing works fine everytime

THE GOAL

I want to use the full size image it just looks much better and gives a good example of how it would look as a wallpaper. Any suggestions welcome I know this a hard topic and i know the picasso library is amazing so if its not possible just let me know

Comment: facing similar issue... you got any solution?

Comment: Swapped to glide library fixed the oom, but now maybe switching to universal image loader or volley